# In my UWP application ComboBox, PointerExited event fired right after we click on the control when IsEditable is False

Tags: xaml, uwp, combobox, winrt-xaml, uwp-xaml

There seems to be a similar question but it is not resolved.

I am using a ComboBox in my WinRT/C++ application and need to show the cursor as Hand while hovering over it. The issue is that while clicking on it, the cursor turns to arrow since PointerExited is fired. I had added code to change cursor to Hand when "PointerEntered" and arrow when "PointerExited".

This issue is seen only when IsEditable is set as False. When the bool flag is True, it works as expected.

I wish to workaround this unnecessary PointerExited firing, i.e, as long as I'm in the combobox area I want to show "Hand".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Combobox is made of two main parts. One is a `ContentPresenter` that shows the selected item, another is a `PopUp` that shows the items. The **PointerEntered** event you are handling belongs to the `ContentPresenter` part. When you click the Combobox and the `PopUp` overlays on the `ContentPresenter` part, the **PointerExited** will be fired because the cursor is entering the `PopUp`. Currently, there is no way to avoid this behavior.

There is no perfect solution for this. A workaround is that you could handle the **PointerEntered** event of the `ScrollViewer` which is inside the `PopUp`. Change the cursor type into hands in that event like what you did in the **PointerEntered** event and **PointerExited ** event of the `Combobox`.

Please check the following steps:

1. Get the default style of `ComboBox` control from generic.xaml file and apply the style to your `ComboBox` control.
2. Find the `ScrollViewer` control in the added style, and add event handlers for **PointerEntered** event and **PointerExited** event.
3. Change the cursor type in the handlers.

This is the basic steps, you might need to check other logic like selected item changes to make sure the cursor is in the correct type in such scenarios.

Comment: Thank you for the help. We decided to accept the behavior as it and moved on.